# HTML: Why do my video files have double standards?

Tags: css, html, video, autoplay

I have my code in the html like this for a 40 second video I want on my website. The video converter that I used made my imovie video with an extra video type as you can see below. Is this is what's causing the video not to show up?

```
<video>
<source src="Hai_Fusion_landing_video.oggtheora.ogv" type="video/.ogv" />    
<source src="Hai_Fusion_landing_video.webmhd.webm" type="video/.webm" />
<sporce src="Hai_Fusion_landing_video.mp4.mp4" type="video/.mp4" />
</video>
```

and my inline styling like this

```
<style>
    video{
        min-width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
}
</style>
```

Nothing shows up. Also, does the video files have to be from your desktop or do you have to upload them online first so it is sourced from there before playing?

I would also like for it to autoplay and loop on silence if that helps.

Comment: You have to upload the files to your server (and use a correct URL). Otherwise, how could the user access them?

Comment: what if you add a controls option: <video width="400" controls> (maybe remove the CSS first). Also, they put "Your browser does not support HTML5 video." as a fourth option inside the <video> tag.

Comment: Add files to my server? How do I do that? Sorry, I am new to HTML. And how do I use a correct URL?

Answer (score 0):

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="Hai_Fusion_landing_video.webmhd.webm" type="video/webm" />
  <sporce src="Hai_Fusion_landing_video.mp4.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

I honestly don't know about an `.ogv` video format support in major browsers.

- Remove the dots in the extension type
- Add a "does not support message" in case it's an old browser
- Check if your video files are in the same folder as your html file, if not, your paths won't work. (Learn about [**relative paths**](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/))

Thanks to *@Scooter* and *@Ed Cottrel* for pointing out stuff in the comments.

Comment: .ogv is another video format for when .mp4 or webm don't work. Don't take it from me, but this is what I learned from in a youtube tutorial. The person used this format. Plus, I want to make it a background video filling up the entirety of my whole website. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help out undefined.